# Cannot read parameters from Msxml2.XMLHTTP ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cannot read parameter in PageHandler when using Msxml2.XMLHTTP ajax call.

```
function InvokeHandler() {
      InitXmlHttp();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = XMLHttpRequestCompleted;
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "BookmarkletHandler.ashx?target=ww1", true);
      xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

I even tried:

```
function InvokeHandler() {
      InitXmlHttp();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = XMLHttpRequestCompleted;
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "BookmarkletHandler.ashx", true);
      xmlhttp.send("target=ww1");
  }


function InvokeHandler() {
      InitXmlHttp();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = XMLHttpRequestCompleted;
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "BookmarkletHandler.ashx", true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      xmlhttp.send("target=ww1");
  }
```

Here how i am trying to read in HTTPHandler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   String param = context.Request.QueryString["target"]; --> this gives null
}
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is work:
    function send()
    {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

```
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "about.aspx", true);
  //must have
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  xmlhttp.send("fname=1");
  }
```

in ProcessRequest method:
    var res2 = context.Request.Form;